# Нужно показать фонды согласно категории, выбранной в пункте 1

Tags: javascript, python, django

Пишу django-приложение: необходимо взять из базы данных (шаг 1) категории и на их оcновании (шаг 3) показать фонды, которые относятся к данным категориям. Как это можно сделать? Спасибо!

Мой код:

```
TYPE = (
    (1, 'фонд'),
    (2, 'общественная организация'),
    (3, 'чтото'),
)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Institution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE, default=1)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def type_name(self):
        return TYPE[self.type - 1][1]

class Donation(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    pick_up_date = models.DateField()
    pick_up_time = models.TimeField()
    pick_up_comment = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    is_taken = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    taken_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)    


class DonationView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        all_category = Category.objects.all()
        all_institution = Institution.objects.all()
        context = {
            'all_category': all_category,
            'all_institution': all_institution,
        }
        return render(request, 'form.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            institution_name = request.POST.get('organization')
            institution = Institution.objects.get(name=institution_name)
            categories_names = request.POST.getlist('categories')
            categories_ids = []
            for category_name in categories_names:
                category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
                categories_ids.append(category.id)
            quantity = request.POST.get('bags')
            address = request.POST.get('address')
            phone_number = request.POST.get('phone')
            city = request.POST.get('city')
            zip_code = request.POST.get('postcode')
            pick_up_date_str = request.POST.get('data')
            pick_up_date = datetime.strptime(pick_up_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
            pick_up_time = request.POST.get('time')
            pick_up_comment = request.POST.get('more_info')
            new_donation = Donation.objects.create(quantity=quantity, institution=institution,
                                                   address=address, phone_number=phone_number, city=city,
                                                   zip_code=zip_code, pick_up_date=pick_up_date,
                                                   pick_up_time=pick_up_time,
                                                   pick_up_comment=pick_up_comment, user=request.user)

            new_donation.save()
            return render(request, 'form-confirmation.html')
        except Exception:
            return HttpResponseServerError('Error')
```

код js:

```
let selectedCategories = [];
let selectedInstitution = [];
let numberOfBags = 0;
let selectedAddress = {};
let selectedDate = {};

document.querySelector('div[data-step="1"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectedCategories = [];

    const checkedCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="categories"]:checked');

    checkedCheckboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        selectedCategories.push(checkbox.value);
    });

    filterOrganizationsByCategory(selectedCategories);
        updateSummaryText();
});

document.querySelector('div[data-step="2"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[name="bags"]');
    numberOfBags = parseInt(inputElement.value);
console.log(selectedCategories)
    updateSummaryText();
});

document.querySelector('div[data-step="3"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectedInstitution = [];

    const checkedInstitutions = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="organization"]:checked');

    checkedInstitutions.forEach((checkbox) => {
        selectedInstitution.push(checkbox.value);
    });

    updateSummaryText();
});

}
```

HTML

```
      <form action="" method="post" >
        {%  csrf_token %}
          <!-- STEP 1: class .active is switching steps -->
          <div data-step="1" class="active">
            <h3>Что хочешь отдать:</h3>
                  {%  for category in all_category %}
            <div class="form-group form-group--checkbox">
              <label>

                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="categories"
                  value="{{ category.name }}"
                />
                <span class="checkbox"></span>
                                  <span class="description"
                  >{{ category }}</span>

              </label>
            </div>
                  {% endfor %}

            <div class="form-group form-group--buttons">
              <button type="button" class="btn next-step">Dalej</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="step1_data" value="{{ data_from_step1 }}" />

          <!-- STEP 2 -->
          <div data-step="2">
            <h3>количество мешков:</h3>

            <div class="form-group form-group--inline">
              <label>
                количество мешков:
                <input type="number" name="bags" step="1" min="1" />
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group form-group--buttons">
              <button type="button" class="btn prev-step">Wstecz</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn next-step">Dalej</button>
            </div>
          </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="step2_data" value="{{ data_from_step2 }}" />



          <!-- STEP 3 -->
          <div data-step="3" id="step-3">
            <h3>Выбери фонд:</h3>
        {% for institution in all_institution %}
            <div class="form-group form-group--checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="organization" value="{{ institution.name }}" data-category="">
                <span class="checkbox radio"></span>
                <span class="description">
                  <div class="title">{{ institution.name }}</div>
                  <div class="subtitle">
                    {{ institution.description }}
                  </div>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
              {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Что именно вы не смогли сделать?

Comment: в step 3 необходимо отсортировать фонды согласно категориям и показать только соответствующие этой или этим категориям, вот это у меня не выходит